# How inefficient would this query be and also table structure?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One table stores course_updates, which basically has a new row pushed to it everytime someone adds or drops a course. I also have another table follower_updates that has a record pushed to it whenever someone follows someone. I want to be able to get the information for the logged in user, but I'm unsure how I should detect which table the information is coming from being that I want to display the information based upon which table it is from. Should I make a new column that update_type, or should I have a different method?
I'm also going to show what I'm thinking relatively in terms of sql. It won't be perfect because I haven't tested it yet. This is just a sample. I didn't want to bring in my current query because just the course_updates already has three inner joins and an outerjoin, so I tried to streamline the content for this question. thanks!

```
SELECT * FROM course_updates WHERE (establishes connection 
enter code herebetween user and courses and followers)
UNION SELECT * FROM follower_updates WHERE followee.id = currentUser.id etc.
```

Comment: What information exactly do you want to display for `course_updates` and what information exactly do you want to display for `follower_updates`?

Comment: For course updates, I'm simply storing whenever a user adds or removes a course. So I store a course id and a uID as well as the action. As for follower updates, I'm storing information regarding who follows who when. I'm finding out that I won't be able to align my columns. I'm thinking that I may switch to a different table structure where I have updates, user_updates and course_updates. course_updates will store the course number timestamp and an id reference to the updates table where I will have an updateObject stored via json. This will lead to data redundancy in the database though.

Comment: The data redundancy will occur because I will need to store data in the course updates for the user adding a course, but I'd also have to store the same information in the user_updates table in order to get the same information if a user is following someone. Ultimately, a nosql solution would probably be best, but I'm trying to stick to SQL. I'm not sure how exactly to lay everything out. As is I would need to add a user_update for both users when one followed the other to be able to get the information when I queried the database.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, what you want to *display*. And instead of describing in prose, what you store in the database, the `CREATE TABLE` statements are 1) shorter, 2) easier to read 3) a basis for code by someone who answers your question.

Comment: I want to be able to display an update feed where the user sees personalized updates. For example when one of the users followers follows someone they will see that. If some follows the current user, the user will see that. When someone adds the course that the user subscribes to, they will see that. I also want a system that is easy to expand upon for other updates.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `UNION`. Use two separate queries instead.

Comment: I probably should of included that I want to order the columns by timestamp.. I think that changes things. right?

Comment: should 'have' included